# Oracle Fusion Cloud(Database Version 19c) : SQL Query to get the Payment Term and Payment Method Detials of AR Customer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-fusion-apps

I am bit new to Oracle Fusion Cloud Applications and have been given a task to design a BIP report to fetch the AR Customer Details. I need help to find the table name/joins which stores the Customer Payment Term, Payment Method details. I tried to join hz_cust_site_uses_all and ra_terms with PAYMENT_TERM_ID, TERM_ID but the PAYMENT_TERM_ID is NULL for all the Customers in hz_cust_site_uses_all so did not get any data.
Request you to help me with a query to fetch the Customer Payment Term, Payment Method details.